# Problemas con base de datos y array

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer algo tan sencillo como una conexión a una base de datos y tratar los datos con un array, pero no hay manera estoy bloqueado. Me tira un error busco busco pero no hay manera.

//control

```
 <?php 

    include('../include/conexion.php');

    $user = $_POST['usuario'];
    $pass = $_POST['contrasena'];

    //var_dump($registro);

    foreach ($registro as $registros) {
        $pass_bd = $fila['contrasena'];
        if (password_verify($pass, $pass_bd)) {
        echo "Las contraseñas son iguales";

        }
        else{
            echo "error";
        }
    }
?>
```

//conexion

```
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'test';
    $pass = '1234';
    $db = 'mc_17';

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

    mysqli_query($conexion, 'SET NAMES "utf-8"');

    $sentencia = 'SELECT * FROM Usuarios';
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sentencia);

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $registro[] = $fila;
    }

    //La siguiente me da un error el cual no consigo solucionar ni encontrar info exacta sobre este error.
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Y qué error te devuelve?

Comment: Hola Pedro, pues no me genera ningún error...

Comment: Prueba a obtener el error de conexión (si existe) con '$mysqli->connect_error`, por ejemplo.

Comment: Ok gracias voy a probar

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: contrasena in linea 10 de control.

Comment: Es como si no encontrara contrasena pero si hago un var_dump($registros ); me enseña el array...

Comment: Sergi tu código se ve bien así, debes estar cometiendo algún error escribiendo alguna variable o escribiendo el nombre de la clave del array. ¿Puedes mostrar lo que imprime el `var_dump($registro);` al salir del `while`?, por cierto, ¿se llama `$registro` o `$registros`?... **Nota: No es necesario usar `array_push` para esto que quieres hacer.**

Answer (score 1):

En `conexion` estás creando el array de la forma correcta. No es necesario usar `array_push` para hacerlo.

Tú error está al leer el array que te devuelve `conexion`, específicamente aquí:

<s>`foreach ($registro as $registros) {`</s>

Debería ser:

`foreach ($registro as $fila) {`

ya que luego, dentro del bucle, intentas acceder a los elementos así:

`$fila['contrasena']`

Si lo pones así debería funcionar:

```
<?php 

    include('../include/conexion.php');

    $user = $_POST['usuario'];
    $pass = $_POST['contrasena'];

    //var_dump($registro);

    foreach ($registro as $fila) {
        $pass_bd = $fila['contrasena'];
        if (password_verify($pass, $pass_bd)) {
            echo "Las contraseñas son iguales";
        }
        else{
            echo "error";
        }
    }
?>
```